# Define \norm command and work in long table

Tags: mathtools

### Edit: Solution

`\norm` requires an argument. Thanks to the commenters for pointing that out to me.

### Orig question:

I have a `\norm` command defined that is simply the `\lVert` and `\rVert` symbols put on either side of something. This works completely fine in paragraphs, equations, and other general math mode usages.

However, for whatever reason, attempting to use it in longtable just outputs `Undefined control sequence`. Even defining the command two different ways (as shown in MWE) still results in the error. Any ideas why it isn't working?

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

%% Define \norm using amsmath and mathtools
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}


%% Define \norm using normal command definition
% \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert} %for making the magnitude (norm) of velocity vectors

\begin{document}
% \doublespacing

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}
\noindent\begin{longtable}{@{}l @{\quad=\quad} l@{}}
\(A\) & area \\

\multicolumn{2}{l}{\Large{\textbf{Operators}}}\\
\(\norm\) & vector magnitude\\
\end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

Also, note that the long table settings were simply grabbed from the AIAA example format as this is for the nomenclature section.

Comment: `\norm` requires one argument, e.g. `\norm{x}`.

Comment: Have you tried `\(\norm A\)` instead `\(\norm\)`?

Comment: The issue you're encountering is in no way related to `\norm` being used inside a  `longtable` environment. Instead, it's linked to the fact that `\norm` takes an argument. I believe that what you would (or should?) want to typeset is either `\norm{{}\cdot{}}` or -- not quite as good -- `\norm{\;}` (`\;` inserts "thickspace".)

Comment: You can easily define norm such that given an empty argument `{} `, then it inserts an argument marker instead (as Mico mentions, but simpler)

Comment: Apparantly your aim could be to display the command name `\norm` and not the result with the double bars. In such case, `\string\norm` will typeset the word "norm" with its prefixed backslash.